# Slanted column heading - SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to create an SSRS 2008 report which has **slanted/angled column headers** like in the screenshot below?
I've searched for a solution to this, but haven't found anything of use.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, no, SSRS won't do this. 90 degree rotated text is possible as you've probably seen

You actually have two problems:
1. Slanted text.
2. Non rectangle cells.

There are potential workaround to solve the first problem: create a text graphic on the fly, use stylesheet tricks, &c.

But the second problem will be very difficult if not entirely impossible to solve. SSRS, and many of the formats to which it exports, only support rectangle cells.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was afraid this was going to be the answer, but I had to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to create slanted text in SSRS, but not slanted text boxes. Just paste a column chart into the cell, style the horizontal axis as needed to slant the text at the desired angle, and delete all data series and the vertical axis, title and key from the chart.

If the text is to show at the top of a column that repeats in a column group, assign the same dataset to the chart as the body of the table and filter the chart so that only the relevant column of the chart shows in each column of the expanded table. The filter will look like [HeadingFieldName] = [HeadingFieldName], because you are essentially joining the dataset to itself on this column.